# how can share variables between different apps

Tags: bash, variable, shared-library

**how can update the `foo` variable from another app?**

```bsh
$ cat app1.sh

#!/bin/bash
//foo can be changed from the internet, but for example, I give it foo=1
export foo=1
while true
do
   echo "$foo+2"
   sleep 5
done
```

second app change var by:

```bsh
$ cat app2.sh

#!/bin/bash
export foo=$foo+100
```

the wile loop can't be `unset` the old `foo` value and got a new value from another app, so how can update foo var in while loop without using something like a `database` or `file`?

Comment: Variables are local to each process; you're going to have to use a database or file or something.

Comment: in-memory key=value databases like [memcached](https://memcached.org/) or [redis](https://redis.io/) are useful for this.   They're like an associative array that can be shared with multiple processes (even processes on other machines if the db listens on a reachable IP address - but there are security implications here, you'll need to carefully restrict access).  Your scripts/apps will still have to query the db to get the current value of the key, but you don't have to manually deal with a file in them.

Comment: Make `foo` a file, for example. `echo 0 > /tmp/foo; for ((;;)); do echo $(($(< /tmp/foo) + 2)); sleep 1; done;` Then elsewhere do (e.g.) `echo 100 > /tmp/foo;`. That’s a basic (but still flawed) option. To do things properly, it would be like `echo 100 > /tmp/new_foo; mv /tmp/{new_,}foo;`, to make sure the value swap is atomic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix uses a memory protection model which prevents programs from changing memory that belongs to other programs.

If you want to share data between different programs, you have to use an interprocess communication method. A few such methods include:

- Files in a filesystem
- pipes
- FIFOs (a variation on pipes)
- signals
- shared memory
- sockets

Bash directly supports only the first four of these.